# How to pass value by comma separated to a variable using foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have array with some values after performing foreach loop I want to pass every value to a  variable by comma separated, but last value should not come with comma(,).

```
<?php
$aa=array("id"=>1,"id"=>2,"id"=>3,"id"=>4);


$otherV = '';
foreach($aa as $key => $value){
if (!empty($otherV))
{

   $otherV = $value.",";
}
  else{
      $otherV = $value;
    }

}


echo $otherV;
?>
```

expected output 
I want output like this: 1,2,3,4

Comment: What is `->`? Did you mean `=>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have the same position for each array value

```
$aa=array("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" =>3, "d" => 4);
foreach($aa as $value)
{
   $temp[]=$value;
}
echo implode(",",$temp);
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
<?php
$aaray=array("a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3,"d"=>4);
$otherV = '';
$len = count($aaray);
$i=0;
foreach($aaray as $value){
    $i++;
   //check if this is not the last iteration of foreach
   //then add the `,` after concatenation 
    if ($i != $len) {
       $otherV .= $value.",";
    }else{
        //check if this is the last iteration of foreach
        //then don't add the `,` after concatenation 
        $otherV .= $value;
    }  
}
echo $otherV;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of mistakes in your code

```
<?php
// fix array creation, dont use `->` use `=>`
// and the keys cannot all be the same
$aa=array("a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3,"d"=>4);

$otherV = '';
foreach($aa as $key => $value){
   //concatenate the value into otherV using .=
   $otherV .= $value.",";
}
rtrim( $otherV, ',');  // remove last comma
echo $otherV;
?>
```

Comment: i want all values but your code showing only last value

Comment: Made a typo, check again after refresh page

Comment: still getting same problem

Comment: Ahh, :) Missed the bad array creation. You cannot have 4 items all with the same key ::)